# AutoMapper DSL (Computation Expression) for F#

Tags: f#, framework, dsl, automapper

I have created a DSL for AutoMapper using an F# Computation Expression Builder.  The Computation Builder itself is fairly simple, and effectively defines 5 basic operations:  `map` to map from a field in the source to a field in the destination, `value` to use a specific value for a field in the destination, `ignore` to ignore a field in the destination, `resolve` to use an `IValueResolver` to populate a field in the destination, and `convert` to use an `ITypeConverter`.  There are also `define` and `endMap` keywords to signify the beginning and end of the map respectively, and a special `ignoreRest` custom operation to ignore all un-mapped fields in the destination.

The source code for the Computation Builder is as follows:

```
namespace AutoMapper.FSharp

open AutoMapper
open FSharp.Quotations
open FSharp.Linq.RuntimeHelpers
open System
open System.Linq.Expressions

type MappingProfile () =
    inherit Profile()

type MappingProfileBuilder () =
    let mutable profile = Unchecked.defaultof<MappingProfile>
    let toLinq (expr : Expr<'a -> 'b>) =
        let linq = expr |> LeafExpressionConverter.QuotationToExpression
        let call = linq |> unbox<MethodCallExpression>
        let lambda = call.Arguments.[0] |> unbox<LambdaExpression>
        Expression.Lambda<Func<'a, 'b>>(lambda.Body, lambda.Parameters) 
    member __.Yield x = 
        profile <- new MappingProfile()
        profile
    [<CustomOperation("define")>]
    member this.Define<'source, 'destination> (profile: MappingProfile) =        
        profile.CreateMap<'source, 'destination>()
    [<CustomOperation("map")>]
    member this.Map (map: IMappingExpression<'source, 'destination>, [<ReflectedDefinition>] s: Expr<'source -> 'sourceMember>, [<ReflectedDefinition>] d: Expr<'destination -> 'destinationMember>) =
        let mapTo = d |> toLinq
        let mapFrom = Action<IMemberConfigurationExpression<'source, 'destination, 'destinationMember>> (fun (opts: IMemberConfigurationExpression<'source, 'destination, 'destinationMember>) -> opts.MapFrom(s |> toLinq))
        map.ForMember(mapTo, mapFrom)
    [<CustomOperation("ignore")>]
    member this.Ignore (map: IMappingExpression<'source, 'destination>, [<ReflectedDefinition>] x: Expr<'destination -> 'destintaionMember>) = 
        let mapTo = x |> toLinq
        let mapFrom = Action<IMemberConfigurationExpression<'source, 'destination, 'destintaionMember>> (fun (opts: IMemberConfigurationExpression<'source, 'destination, 'destintaionMember>) -> opts.Ignore())
        map.ForMember(mapTo, mapFrom)
    [<CustomOperation("value")>]
    member this.Value (map: IMappingExpression<'source, 'destination>, [<ReflectedDefinition>] x: Expr<'destination -> 'destintaionMember>, v: 'destinationMember) =
        let mapTo = x |> toLinq
        let mapFrom = Action<IMemberConfigurationExpression<'source, 'destination, 'destinationMember>> (fun (opts: IMemberConfigurationExpression<'source, 'destination, 'destinationMember>) -> opts.UseValue(v))
        map.ForMember(mapTo, mapFrom)
    [<CustomOperation("resolve")>]
    member this.Resolve (map: IMappingExpression<'source, 'destination>, [<ReflectedDefinition>] x: Expr<'destination -> 'destintaionMember>, r: IValueResolver<'source, 'destination, 'destinationMember>) =
        let mapTo = x |> toLinq
        let mapFrom = Action<IMemberConfigurationExpression<'source, 'destination, 'destinationMember>> (fun (opts: IMemberConfigurationExpression<'source, 'destination, 'destinationMember>) -> opts.ResolveUsing(r))
        map.ForMember(mapTo, mapFrom)
    [<CustomOperation("convert")>]
    member this.Convert (map: IMappingExpression<'source, 'destination>, c: ITypeConverter<'source, 'destination>) =
        map.ConvertUsing(c)
        map
    [<CustomOperation("ignoreRest")>]
    member this.IgnoreRest (map: IMappingExpression<'source, 'destination>) =
        map.ForAllOtherMembers(Action<IMemberConfigurationExpression<'source, 'destination, obj>> (fun (opts: IMemberConfigurationExpression<'source, 'destination, obj>) -> opts.Ignore()))
        map
    [<CustomOperation("endMap")>]
    member this.EndMap (map: IMappingExpression<'source, 'destination>) =
        profile :> Profile

[<AutoOpen>]
module MapBuilder =
    let automapper = MappingProfileBuilder()
```

Before using the computation builder, we'll need a test model to use in a map:

```
namespace AutoMapper.FSharp.TestModel

open System

[<CLIMutable>]
type InputObject =
    {
        Name: string
        Value: int
        Date: DateTime
        Coordinates: (int*int) list
    }

[<CLIMutable>]
type Coordinate = 
    {X: int; Y: int}

[<CLIMutable>]
type OutputObject =
    {
        Id: Guid
        Description: string
        CoreValue: int
        Time: DateTime
        Coordinates: Coordinate list
        IsComplete: bool
    }
```

Now, using the `automapper` Computation Expression, we can define a map from `InputObject` to `OutputObject` as follows:

```
namespace AutoMapper.FSharp

open AutoMapper
open AutoMapper.FSharp.TestModel
open System

module Maps =
    let coordinateResolver =
        {new IValueResolver<InputObject, OutputObject, Coordinate list> with
            member __.Resolve(source, destination, destinationMember, context) =
                source.Coordinates |> List.map (fun (x,y) -> {X = x; Y = y})
        }

    let inputObjectToOutputObject = 
        automapper {
            define
            value   (fun (d: OutputObject) -> d.Id)  (Guid.NewGuid())
            map     (fun (s: InputObject) -> s.Name) (fun d -> d.Description)
            map     (fun s -> s.Value)               (fun d -> d.CoreValue)
            map     (fun s -> s.Date)                (fun d -> d.Time)
            resolve (fun d -> d.Coordinates)         coordinateResolver
            ignoreRest
            endMap
        }
```

And for good measure, here's a Test program that brings everything together and executes the example map:

```
open AutoMapper
open AutoMapper.FSharp
open AutoMapper.FSharp.TestModel
open System

module Test =
    [<EntryPoint>]
    let main argv = 
        let config = AutoMapper.Configuration.MapperConfigurationExpression()
        config.AddProfile(Maps.inputObjectToOutputObject)
        Mapper.Initialize(config)
        printf "Name: "
        let name = Console.ReadLine()
        printf "Value: "
        let value = Console.ReadLine() |> Int32.Parse
        printf "X = "
        let x = Console.ReadLine() |> Int32.Parse
        printf "Y = "
        let y = Console.ReadLine() |> Int32.Parse
        let inputObject =
            {
                Name = name;
                Value = value;
                Date = DateTime.Now;
                Coordinates = [0,0; x,y]
            }
        printfn "Input Object: %A" inputObject
        let outputObject = Mapper.Map<InputObject, OutputObject>(inputObject)
        printfn "Output Object: %A" outputObject
        printfn"\r\nPress any key to exit..."
        Console.ReadKey() |> ignore
        0 // return an integer exit code
```

I'd welcome feedback on the Computation Builder implementation, and the design of the DSL itself.  I'm still on the fence about the source/destination left/right column alignment.  I went with what seemed intuitive to me, but I'm not quite happy with it yet, especially as sometimes the destination field expressions are on the left (such as when using `resolve` or `value`).  Let me know what you would do differently.

Answer (score 1):

This is a really cool idea. As far as limiting the cognitive overhead of the lambdas, you could do a combination of what Gjallarhorn and Argu do:

The idea from Gjallarhorn is to have the user create a [dummy value](https://github.com/ReedCopsey/Gjallarhorn.Bindable/blob/master/samples/ElmInspiredOne/ElmInspiredOne/Program.fs#L37) of the type you want to make a lambda of, and then instead of a lambda have the user just [access a property](https://github.com/ReedCopsey/Gjallarhorn.Bindable/blob/master/samples/ElmInspiredOne/ElmInspiredOne/Program.fs#L46) on that type:

```
let dummyInput: InputObject = // your dummy code goes here

let dummyOutput: OutputObject = // ditto
... some time passes ... 


let inputObjectToOutputObject = 
        automapper {
            map     dummyInput.Name         dummyOutput.Description
            map     dummyInput.Value        dummyOutput.CoreValue
            map     dummyInput.Date         dummyOutput.Time
            resolve dummyOutput.Coordinates coordinateResolver
            ignoreRest
            endMap
        }
```

etc, etc

Now, the part you could take from Argu is to [decorate your builder](https://github.com/fsprojects/Argu/blob/master/src/Argu/ParseResults.fs#L64) methods that take `IMappingExpression` to instead take `Expr<something>` and use `ReflectedDefinition(true)` attribute to turn those property accesses into Expressions automatically. What you get from that looks something like this:

```
type Foo = { Bar: string}
let thing = { Bar = "lol" }
<@ thing.Bar @>

> type Foo =
  {Bar: string;}
val thing : Foo = {Bar = "lol";}
val it : Quotations.Expr<string> =
  PropertyGet (Some (PropertyGet (None, thing, [])), Bar, [])
```

And then you could translate simple propertyGets like that into the IMappingExpression for the user.

Just an idea. Otherwise I really like the idea!

Comment: In your second suggestion, the "Argu" way, how does the user pass the required `ProperyGet` expression to the Computation Builder (I'm already using `ReflectedDefinition`) without an instance of the types being mapped on which to access the property?  I kept the lambdas because otherwise, as in your first example, you need some dummy instances of the types being mapped, but if you know of a way to get around that, I'd be all for it.